# Securing API Secrets On Clients Using Custom API

Tags: javascript, php, rest

I am writing a mobile application using Phonegap/Cordova.
The mobile application needs information from a server-side application, which I have written. I created an API to get this information.

One of the first things the API does is verify the mobile application is an application which I have written.
It does this using a public API key and a secret API key. (They are used in generating the authorization header).

The authorization header is generated on the mobile application and on the server-side application and the server will check them against eachother for discrepancies.

It goes something like this:

### Mobile Application (Javascript/jQuery)

```
var SIGNATURE = SHA512( MY_APP + MY_PUBLIC_API_KEY + TIMESTAMP + NONCE + MY_SECRET_API_KEY );
var auth = "path=MY_APP,key=MY_PUBLIC_API_KEY,time=TIMESTAMP,nonce=NONCE,signature=SIGNATURE"
$.ajax( { 
    type = "POST", 
    url: url, 
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
} );
```

### Server Side (PHP)

```
// there is some regex to "decode" the auth header
// now, recreate the signature from the public variables in the auth header and check for a match (note: this includes fetching the secret from an xml file as it is not in the public information)
```

The problem obviously lies in the fact that I need the secret API key to generate the signature on the client side.

After reading articles online, a lot of people have said to store the secret on the server (then use the server as an intermediary), but I believe that only applies if you're using a third party API.
This also just moves the problem away from the client. What stops somebody from just making a call to the intermediary, which will just stick the secret on anyway?

A very similar solution is to store the secret on the server and fetch it when the app loads, but surely that's the same problem...what's stopping somebody from simply going to `api.mydomain.com/getsecretkey`?

Storing secrets on the client is just not viable. Especially with phonegap. So how do people do it?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I have the *source-code* (obfuscated or not ...) of your application on my phone, I *can* determine how any handshake-value is computed or checked.  Therefore, I *can,* if I am determined enough, masquerade as your application.

Comment: If I understood you well, you can't. But, why on earth could you want to do that???

I understand you could want to authenticate users, but why applications?

If your API works well, then no client could do something wrong, even your app. And, if not, any mistake in your applicattion could mess your data.

So why not make a robust API and don't care about which client is connecting to it?

Comment: As a side note, don't use MD5, it has been considered insecure for several years now. If you need a hash, use SHA-256 or better.

Comment: @bitifet The secret is my way of ensuring the Authorization header has been sent only by authorized apps and to ensure the Authorization header has not been tampered with... i.e. You cannot recreate the signature without it, so the request would fail. To give further context, when the user opens the app, they first need to enter a license key, so there are no credentials thus far.

Comment: @jcaron I am, in fact, using SHA-512, I didn't check and MD5 was the first that came to mind. (I'll update my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the bottom line here is just: "you can't do it."  The work is being done on the *user's* machine, using *source* code that is also present on the machine.  Therefore, a determined thief can discern all of your "secrets," and there's nothing that you can do about it.

You *can* add various forms of checks to your host that simply look for something that is required to be present in every request, and to refuse to respond *(even, "just drop the packet")* if this characteristic is not there. This would, for example, allow you to ignore "junk" requests that are being thrown at you by some script-kiddie's robot:   they'd have to have a copy of your client-side application in order to figure out how to phrase their message correctly, and that automatically implies "a more-determined, less-than-casual thief."  (Many of the attackers on the Internet are just trying to make noise and cause mischief, and it's worth your while *(IMHO)* to do a little something to let you ignore such things quickly.)

Comment: I think you're right. There's just no feasible way to verify the app. I'm going to need to rethink and implement the checks you suggested. Thank you

Comment: Also, it's possible to use the TLS security protocol more-aggressively than HTTPS web-sites ordinarily do.  You can install certificates on the client side as part of your application and verify that anyone connecting to your API has them, again using this to let you discard queries that are bogus.  But, even so, it is impossible to "keep a secret" on the client side, and there is no "security by obscurity."  I suggest, "just put a few things in to let you packet-drop incoming bogosity," and call it a day ...

Answer (score 0):

On the server you may detect your "authentication" data first, like checking the required basic data, user-agent and etc etc.

Second, try to encrypt your data, you may use the app secret first to get a new key to your server (for the next session), and then use the retrivered new key as next encryption key.

 **End to End** encryption are suggested.

`JWT.io` liblaries may help those issue. https://jwt.io/

And your server may refuse the connection or send the error code if those requirements didn't meet.

Comment: Problem is that this solution relies on the app keeping its secret and sending it to the server. 2 problems with that: (1) if the app holds a secret, the user can look at the code and steal it. (2) if the app sends its secret over the internet, the user who controls access to the internet can steal it when the app first communicates in the clear.  Besides, all that doesn't solve the OP's challenge: how to know if the app has been modified? These challenges are the reason we have yet to get a strong answer to this question.

Comment: hmm, i think if that's coming, you can create a **random code generator**, so nobody will see it as a constant code. And then try to obfuscate it. On the server, you can make the prooffers where certain algoritm recognizes the code.

Comment: And then for people who has control over the internet, we could prevent it by Encrypting the data it self. The thing that still remain unencrypted is the server's host address. and not the URI. This quite strong too if user didn't know which address are being accessed.

Comment: I think I will have to rely on SSL encryption to ensure the request hasn't been intercepted and modified. Don't think there's another way